# Splitting data inside quotes and comma using regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I am struggling to prepare regex for the following data

I have input like this

```
"%,.2f","mm/DD/YYYY","1"
```

I wanted to have a result like this

```
%,.2f
mm/DD/YYYY
1
```

I tried with multiple Regex but nothing works.

Is there a way to get this in Java?

I am writing a parser in a internal framework which parse method and arguments like `formatCurrency("%,.2f","mm/DD/YYYY","1")`. I have written a regex to get function name and arguments separately.

There are some constraints for using comma splitter because function parameters can also contain a comma. I think even splitting with quotes will have the same problem. I thought the only way is to parse using regex but understanding regex is difficult...

Regex to parse this would be more helpful

Comment: Are you trying to parse CSV with a regex? There are libraries that handle the special cases and do all of this for you.

Comment: If it's that rigid of an input rule (And you use it a lot) you could do this with substringing instead

Comment: I usually find substring code to be brittle, and regex code to be unreadable.

Comment: Edited my question with more details

Answer (score 1):

You want to split the String between two quotation marks `"` with the comma `,` as a delimiter.

This Regex captures the needed Strings in case you keep the format:

```
"(.*?)"
```

[Demo at Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Ksy37s/1)

Here is the same in Java code that might be better for you. Don't forget to escape `\"` the quotation marks. It would be understood as the String end/start otherwise:

```
List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\"(.*?)\"") .matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    results.add(m.group(1));
}
```

Comment: `m.group()` -> `m.group(1)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Matcher` and `find()` each column:

```
String s = "\"%,.2f\",\"mm/DD/YYYY\",\"1\"";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?<=(?:^|,)\")([^\"]*)(?=\")").matcher(s);
List<String> cols = new ArrayList<>();
while (m.find()) {
    cols.add(m.group(1)); // group(0) works, too
}

System.out.println(cols);
// [%,.2f, mm/DD/YYYY, 1]
```

It's also somewhat easy to make the surrounding quotes optional, but there's a joke about regular expressions being write-only for a reason.

A bit of an explanation on the regex:

All quotes have to be escaped because of Java strings, so you'll see things like `[^\"]*` in the pattern.

> `(?<=(?:^|,)\")`

matches the comma and quote before the text

> `(?<=...)`

Non-capturing positive look-behind. It lets you look behind the text you're trying to match, even if those characters were already matched in a previous pattern. It also means `group(0)` won't contain the comma or quote, so it's more fool-proof.

> `(?:^|,)\"`

Match either the beginning of a line or a comma, followed up a quote, but don't capture the comma (again, for `group(0)` to work, and for `group(1)` to not be `"`"`.

> `([^\"]*)`

Match as many non-quote characters as possible and capture them. They'll be in `group(1)` since this is the first *capturing* group in the pattern.

> `(?=\")`

Look ahead for a closing quote. This won't be included in `group(0)` because it's look-ahead.

Comment: Maybe you could explain your (complicated) pattern more and why it would be preferable to the much simpler pattern in Nikolas Charalambidis' answer. Your constraints with look-behind and look-ahead ensure a more proper match, but no regex-beginner will be able to make sense of what you've written.

Comment: Can you explain this regex?

Comment: Updated. Let me know if it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea to try to parse a CSV file by yourself. The format has a lot of corner cases and for serious products only I recommend you to use an existing library.

I recommend you to use [Apache COMMONS CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/user-guide.html):

Just add the dependency in your POM file:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The code is quite straight forward:

```
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

/**
 */
public class CSVTester
{
    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException
    {
        String csvLine = "\"%,.2f\",\"mm/DD/YYYY\",\"1\"";

        List<CSVRecord> records = CSVParser.parse(csvLine, CSVFormat.DEFAULT).getRecords();

        records.stream().forEach(record -> {
            System.out.printf("%s\n%s\n%s",
                    record.get(0), record.get(1), record.get(2));
        });
    }
}
```

The output should be as expected:

```
%,.2f
mm/DD/YYYY
1
```

Also I only go to RegEx when there's nothing else left in my arsenal.

The code doesn't look right, they can hide a lot of corner-case bugs, and they are a nightmare to debug and to repair (after a few weeks you will forget how you made the RegEx and you will spend a lot of time trying to re-understand it).

Comment: I have very simple use case to parse two or three comma separated arguments. Using csv parser for this use case looks heavier...

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the following which contains the three scenarios : begin of string, middle of string, end of string

```
(^"|","|"$)
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yudd4A/1)**

- `^"` will match the ones at the beginning of your string
- `","` will match de middle ones
- `"$` will match the ones at the end

**[IdeOne Demo](https://ideone.com/2EHlJY)**

```
Result : [, %,.2f, mm/DD/YYYY", 1]
```